# Matrix Norm Identity Derivation

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I am having trouble figuring out where something in a book I am reading is coming from. (The book is *Matrix Computations* by Golub and Van Loan, 3rd edition, p.58.) It will probably be obvious once someone points it out to me, but until then I am stuck. It stems from the following lemma (which I understand and can follow):

If $ F \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $\|F\|_p < 1$, then $I-F\,\,$ is nonsingular and

$$
\left( I-F \right )^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{F^k}
$$

with

$$
\|\left( I-F \right )^{-1} \|_p \leq { {1} \over {1-\|F\|_p} }.
$$

As a consequence of the above,

$$
\| \left( I - F \right )^{-1} - I \|_p \leq { {\|F\|_p} \over {1-\|F\|_p}}.
$$

It's the last inequality that I cannot figure out how to derive.

Comment: Which book? ${}$

Comment: Golub and Van Loan, Matrix Computations, 3rd edition, p. 58.

Comment: It's a matrix identity trick + triangle ineq. + submultiplicative norm: $(1-F)^{-1}=I+(1-F)^{-1}F$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to percusse in the comments above. The identity provided makes it rather simple:

$$
\left( I - F \right)^{-1} - I = \left( I - F \right)^{-1} F
$$

so

$$
\|(I-F)^{-1} - I\| \leq \|F\| \cdot \|(I-f)^{-1}\| \leq { {\|F\|} \over {1-\|F\|} }
$$